# how to set the callable function parameters of 'before_handler' in cherrypy

Tags: cherrypy

`def do_redirect():
    raise cherrypy.HTTPRedirect("/login.html")`

`def check_auth(call_func):
    # do check ...
    if check_success():
        return
    call_func()`

`cherrypy.tools.auth = cherrypy.Tool('before_handler', check_auth)
cherrypy.tools.auth.call_func = do_redirect`

I want to set the function do_redirect as check_auth's parameter, 
but it throw the follow exception:
    TypeError: check_auth() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)

but it can works if modify to follow code:

`def check_auth(call_func):
    # do check ...
    if check_success():
        return
    cherrypy.tools.auth.call_func()`


`cherrypy.tools.auth = cherrypy.Tool('before_handler', check_auth)
cherrypy.tools.auth.call_func = do_redirect`

how to set the callable function parameters of 'before_handler' in cherrypy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of way on setting the argument for a tool, take a look to this example:

```
import cherrypy as cp


def check_success():
    return False

def do_redirect():
    raise cp.HTTPRedirect("/login.html")

def fancy_redirect():
    raise cp.HTTPRedirect("/fancy_login.html")

def secret_redirect():
    raise cp.HTTPRedirect("/secret_login.html")

def check_auth(call_func=do_redirect):
    # do check ...
    if check_success():
        return
    call_func()

cp.tools.auth = cp.Tool('before_handler', check_auth, priority=60)

class App:

    @cp.expose
    @cp.tools.auth() # use the default
    def index(self):
        return "The common content"

    @cp.expose
    def fancy(self):
        return "The fancy content"

    @cp.expose
    @cp.tools.auth(call_func=secret_redirect) # as argument
    def secret(self):
        return "The secret content"

    @cp.expose
    def login_html(self):
        return "Login!"

    @cp.expose
    def fancy_login_html(self):
        return "<h1>Please login!</h1>"

    @cp.expose
    def secret_login_html(sel):
        return "<small>Psst.. login..</small>"


cp.quickstart(App(), config={
    '/fancy': {
        'tools.auth.on': True,
        'tools.auth.call_func': fancy_redirect  # from config
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```py
cherrypy.tools.auth = HandlerWrapperTool(newhandler=auth_fn)
```

or

```py
class AuthHandler(Tool):
    def __init__(self, auth_fn):
        self._point = 'before_handler'
        self._name = 'auth_handler'
        self._priority = 10
        self._auth_fn = auth_fn


    def callable(self):
        # implementation
```